# If $A \subset B$, then $\inf(A) \geq \inf(B)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let A, B be non-empty bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. If $A \subset  B$, then $\inf(A) \geq \inf(B)$, and give examples of such sets where

(i) $\inf(A) \gt \inf(B)$

(ii)
$\inf(A) = \inf(B)$

For the first part I have:

Let $m = \inf(B)$

$m \leq b, \forall b \in B$ as $A \subset B$

$\Rightarrow$ $m \leq a, \forall a \in A$

$\Rightarrow$ $m \leq \inf(A)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\inf(A) \geq \inf(B)$

Is this correct, and what would be examples for the second two parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the first part is correct.

$A=\{2\}, B=\{1,2\}$ gives an example where $A \subset B$ but $\inf A =2>1=\inf B$.

For the last part take $A=\{1\}, B=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: I thought $\subset$ meant that A cannot equal B

Comment: I have already edited my answer. @user100000

Comment: Sorry I did not see, thank you

Answer (score 1):

consider following set

$$A = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \geq1, n \in \mathbb{N} \} , B = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \geq2, n \in \mathbb{N} \} $$

clearly $B \subset A$ and $\inf A = 0 = \inf B$

Comment: but $\inf(A)$ = 1 and $\inf(B)$ = 1/2

Comment: @user100000 are u sure :) check again?

Comment: yes don't know what I was thinking haha, Thanks very much